# Flutter: widget similar to BottomModalSheet but user can interact with the rest of the app

Tags: flutter, widget, bottom-sheet

I am searching for a widget in flutter that looks like bottom modal sheet, but lets the user interact with the rest of the app.
For example, in Google Maps app, you can touch the map while the bottom sheet is showing.
Any way I can do this?

Comment: Then create a custom widget using Container and other widgets

Comment: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ScaffoldState/showBottomSheet.html

Answer (score 1):

Actually, I think you might be looking for the DraggableScrollableSheet.

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/DraggableScrollableSheet-class.html

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding, I think you are looking for a bottom navigation bar than you should refer: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/BottomNavigationBar-class.html

If you want a better solution then you have to ask your question in detail.